# RethinkDB: Loading A NodeJS package inside r.js method

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I am not sure is it possible or not. 
I need to use a t-distribution in my ReQL from a nodeJS Package. The code is something like this:

```
    Query.map(function(doc){
      return {
               'DesScore': r.do(doc('MXt'),
                                doc('MXdf'), 
                                r.js('(function(v,df){
                                       var distributions = require("distributions.js");
                                       var studentt = distributions.Studentt(df);
                                       return studentt.inv(-1.*Math.abs(v))*2.*100.;}) '))
             };
    })
```

But I get

```
Unhandled rejection ReqlQueryLogicError: ReferenceError: require is not defined in:
```

How can I load a package in ReQL js interpreter?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's `r` (#doc, #js, etc.)?

Comment: r is rethinkDB namespace

Comment: Are you intending to pass in a function as a string here? Don't quite see what you're doing here, but I'm not super familiar w/ Rethink itself. Maybe add some background info?

Comment: I don't know any other way to call a js function in ReQL except the above one. There, I passed `doc('MXt')` and  `doc('MXdf')` as the arguments of the js function( I assumed these two are parts of the `Query` which are passed to `map` function). Inside the js function, I need to call a method from and external nodejs' package and as you can see in the error message, the js interpreter does not have any idea about it. I'm wondering how can I load that package?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `require` in `r.js` because it's JavaScript v8, not NodeJS. `require` is come from NodeJS API, it isn't in standard JavaScript. On JavaScript client side, people use browserify (or friend) for that purpose. So to use `require`, you have to implement a shim for require inside `r.js`, which may also pull it other dependencies...

More than that, you also have to somehow distribute your dependencies to RethinkDB server itself for require to work.

All of those are a mess. So probably try to find another solution.

Think of `r.js` as the last way to do something, and try to use native ReQL whenever possible, as the document say:

https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/js/

With control structure like `forEeach`, `do`, `branch` I think you can do pretty much stuff with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kureikain. I don't know how to write t-distribution and/or gamma function etc. by ReQL (which is what I wanted to load from nodejs package) while ReQL even does not support a simple sqrt. I think rethinkDB requires UDF feature for such scenarios. As much as I try rethinkDB, I understand it is not mature yet.